# Unable to connect to internet and perform https operations in android

Tags: android, google-directions-api

I'm using google cloud's direction API to receive routes between two locations.
However, I'm not able to receive any response from the connection. Instead, I get the following error.

```
2020-06-20 16:19:11.509 8992-9936/com.example.mindyourroute W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lr@519d7e1
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1602)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1693)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:714)
        at cg.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202115050@20.21.15 (040406-0):1)
        at cg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202115050@20.21.15 (040406-0):6)
        at ls.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202115050@20.21.15 (040406-0):10)
        at ld.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202115050@20.21.15 (040406-0):3)
        at ea.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202115050@20.21.15 (040406-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at iz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202115050@20.21.15 (040406-0):6)
```

my java code:

```
public void setDirections(LatLng a, LatLng b){
        UrlRequest.Callback callback = new UrlRequest.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void onRedirectReceived(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info, String newLocationUrl) throws Exception {
                Log.i("redirect_recieved",info.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponseStarted(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info) throws Exception {
                Log.i("responce_started",info.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onReadCompleted(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info, ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws Exception {
                String result_byte = byteBuffer.toString();
                Log.i("result_recieved",result_byte);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSucceeded(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info) {
                Log.i("succeded","result should be out");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info, CronetException error) {
                Log.i("failed",error.toString());
            }
        };
        String a_string = String.format("%f,%f",a.latitude,a.longitude);
        String b_string = String.format("%f,%f",b.latitude,b.longitude);
        String url = String.format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%s&destination=%s&key=%s",a_string,b_string,getString(R.string.google_maps_key));

        CronetProviderInstaller.installProvider(requireContext());
        CronetEngine cronetEngine = new CronetEngine.Builder(requireContext()).build();
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        UrlRequest.Builder requestBuilder = cronetEngine.newUrlRequestBuilder(
                url, callback, executor);
        requestBuilder.build().start();
    }
```

here `a` and `b` are two LatLngs.
Please Help me with this...

Comment: Do you have restrictions on your API key?

Comment: Have you tried to log the resulting Directions API request you are sending and try to send it through the browser? Do you get any error when you do that?

Comment: Incorrect restrictions on API key may sometime cause this problem. Make sure that you check the [API key best practices documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey) to know more of what API key restriction you should use

Comment: Apparently, I didn't enable directions API on Google cloud. That might have been the cause for the error.